# Symfony2 / Twig - getting array from dynamic array key

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In PHP I would do this:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {

    echo $another_array[$key];

}
```

I can't see how to do that in Twig (in Symfony2). I've tried various things, but this would seem the obvious answer, but it doesn't work. It returns a      'Item "the_index" for "Array" does not exist in'     error.

```
{% for value in array %}

    {% set the_index = loop.index %}
    {{ another_array.the_index }}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The fastest way:

```
{% for key,value in array %}
  {{ another_array[key] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great. I used that to compose the element name of a dynamically generated form. `form_row(form["element_#{element.id}"])`

Answer (score 31):

You can use the [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html).

```
{{ attribute(another_array, the_index) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    {% for value in array %}
       {% set the_index = attribute(another_array,  loop.index) %}
       <li>{{ the_index }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```