# How can I use a dynamic key/value on a second level in twig?

Tags: arrays, symfony, dynamic, twig, key

This is my `group` array:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => Fields {#7444 ▼
    -id: 1
    -name: "ID"
    -unique_id: "6ab8c870ed"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7448 ▶}
    -type: Type {#7525 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: true
      -id: 2
      -name: "hidden"
      -unique_id: "5e1086c862"
      -label: "hidden"
       …2
    }
  }
  1 => Fields {#7526 ▶}
  2 => Fields {#7530 ▶}
  3 => Fields {#7534 ▶}
]
```

This is my `column` array:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "type"
]
```

I know that my id is 1:

```
$id = "1";
```

For each value in my column key I want to print out the according value from my `group` array.

So the result would be:

```
1
ID
hidden
```

I try to achieve this with twig

```
{% for key, value in column %}
   {% for k, v in group %}
      {{ v.[value] }};
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The error is:

> Expected name or number.

NOTE: This [Symfony2 / Twig - getting array from dynamic array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606171/symfony2-twig-getting-array-from-dynamic-array-key) is not helping me, because it only explains how to use the value like this `v[value]` or this `v[key]` but not in the second level like this `v.[value]`.

Comment: I'm sorry the example is a bit unclear to me, so I'm half guessing. I think you are looking for the attribute function `{{ attribute(v, value) }}`. If that does not help, you can always write a Twig Extension and solve the issue in php either by doing the printing inside a function or just using a function to combine both objects/arrays into a simple key value-list which is easier to handle in Twig. If you could clarify the example, e.g. I don't see `$column` being used - is this what the `test` object is in the template part? - and maybe I can give a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two `for`-loops in your code to achieve what you want though,

```
{% for class in classes %}
    if (optionValue == {{ class.id }}) {
        {% for column in columns %}
        var {{ column }} = '{{ attribute(class, column) }}';
        {% endfor %}        
    }
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/dlf3rx)

Comment: Thank you! Tested it. I do not know why I get an error: `Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a string variable ("id").`

Comment: Also the error: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\myEntity could not be converted to string").`

Comment: Did you pass the `classes` you've fetched with doctrine?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, and sorry that I just cannot get it work :/

Comment: classes is rendered like this `array:3 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "type"
]`

Comment: is `class` the key or the value?

Comment: Yesterday, you've commented on you created the `columns` array right? you did something as `$columns = $classes-refColumns` - The `classes` i'm refering to is that one, you need to pass that to the view as well. Did you watch my demo? Issn't that the output u want?

Comment: Ah I know what is the problem. This `{{ attribute(class, column) }}` is working with `name` and `id`, because this is replacing `class.id` and `class.name`. The error occured because of `type` because type has also a subarray. So the access to type would be `class.type.name`. Without `type` it is working. So I need to find out how to handle that specific case